# TinkerPop: Filter by Edge count

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

Sample data: [TinkerPop Modern](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/images/tinkerpop-modern.png)

Summary: I want to find People who have created 2 softwares.

I started with the basics, and got the count properly

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").as("from" ,"to1" )
.repeat(bothE().as("e1").otherV().as("to1").dedup("from", "to1")).times(1)
.emit(filter(hasLabel("Software"))).hasLabel("Software")
.group().by(select("from").by("name")).by(count()).as("c")
```

Result:

```
>> {'Marko': 1, 'Peter': 1, 'Josh': 2}
```

So I tried to apply a filter but its not working (ie. Result is incorrect), what I tried:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").as("from")
.repeat(bothE().as("e1").otherV().as("to1").dedup("from", "to1")).times(1)
.filter(bothE().otherV().hasLabel("Software").count(local).is(eq(1)))
.dedup()
.values("name")
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

---

Sample data:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you just need "person" vertices by edge count I don't really see why you need all that `repeat()` infrastructure. It's just:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').
......1>   filter(outE('created').limit(2).count().is(2))
==>v[4]
```

You only need to count outgoing edges because the schema is such that the "created" label only connects to "software", so you don't need to check the 
"software" vertex label. You `limit(2)` to exit the edge iteration as soon as possible but not before you have the 2 edges you are trying to count.

Comment: repeat was for a use-case like people->server->OS and search like people using more than 2 OS

Comment: your query works, trying to fit it in to a case of multi-hop search